# How to make the variable inside the loop available elsewhere PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have this complex code which writes the contents of an array inside a div using a loop with PHP =>

```
<div class="row"  >
<?php for ($b=0; $b<=($uz-1); $b++) { ?>
<a <?php if($b<($uz-1)){ 
echo "href";} ?>="<?php echo site_url('welcome/index/hamleno/'.($b+1).''); ?>">
<?php echo $hml[$b]."  "; ?></a> <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that I need to compare $b outside of the loop just inside the opening div like this=>

```
<div class="row <?php if( $b==$ti){echo "some-class"} ?> ">
```

I can't figure out a chic way; can anyone help?

Comment: show your full code with loop

Comment: @Umair Shah Thank you for the edit...

Comment: @MartinLoanel which section of the code do you need??

Comment: @Otag : No Problem buddy..Can you share an example too of your raw input data which goes into your PHP code and then also show the output data???

Comment: @Otag : Also where does `$ti` comes from??

Comment: The out put can be viewed at [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2wedv6CAJZ_WHl5elIyWGtUQlE        which are the moves of a chess game!?

Comment: @Otag : Share HTML Code of your Output data in your question..!

Comment: @Umair Shah $ti comes with 'welcome/index/hamleno/'.($b+1) where it is drawn as $ti in this view... I hope this helps but this is not the crux of my question. The question is how can I use $b outside of the loop (even its one before the last version according to the loop)...

Comment: @Umair Shah the code that wrote those moves into the div is the code I posted above...

Comment: You do know that your `$b` or `$ti` variables are only available inside your `for loop` you can't use them outside your loop and never ever before the loop but if you want to get the loop data outside to be able to use it after the loop so there is a way to do that..! like you will get the loop data in an array outside the loop and then you can do things based on that array..!

Comment: Also there is a way to do that but not through php but instead you can do that through JavaScript..!

Comment: @Otag : See I just wrote a simple example for you to understand that as PHP executes your code line by line so anything you can't do changes before in your file based on the code which is placed later in the file..You see here is an example..I am creating array later but I am trying to check array first and hence like that way I am not getting exactly what I expected as : https://eval.in/571938

Comment: Take a look at this..I didn't get first Hi cuz that time my array wasn't set but later I got the 2nd Hi cuz that time my array was set so you should know now that you can't do changes in your code based on later code..Here is the link check it : https://eval.in/571939

Answer (score 1):

For starters, when using a for loop and initializing a counter like `$b` in your example, this counter is created when the loop starts and is destroyed when the loop exits.  You can't access it elsewhere, especially not before the loop creates it, as I think you want to do.  This leaves you two possible solutions:

1. Copy the value to an outside variable before the loop ends, then you can examine the value outside the loop. (after the loop only, though)

OR

2. Create `$b` beforehand, look at it before the loop, then use a while loop and manually increment `$b` as your counter.  Since you create it outside the loop, it will still exist and can be referenced before, during and after the loop.  Here's an example:

   ```
   <div class="row">

     <?php
        $b = 0;

        if ($b == $ti) { echo "some-class"; }

        while ($b <= ($uz-1)) 
        {
           echo '<a ';
           if ($b < ($uz-1)){ echo 'href'; }
           echo '="';
           echo site_url('welcome/index/hamleno/'.($b+1)), '">';
           echo $hml[$b], "  ", '</a>';
           ++$b;
        }
     ?>

   </div>
   ```

Comment: An additional note:  By echoing my desired HTML and PHP data instead of switching back and forth from HTML and inserting multiple PHP tags, the code becomes much more readable.